# Nao simulator installation on Groovy

Tags: nao, virtualbox, macosx, rosinstall, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I want to install the NAO simulator on Groovy, under Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, on a VirtualBox running on SnowLeopard OSX.
I was following this site instructions http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started
I've created the 'rosinstall.txt' file on my ~/catkin_workspace/ folder.
The SVN link I found is http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/humanoid_stacks/nao_robot, since the "SVN information as per section 1.2 on installation page: [http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Installation"](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Installation%22) is none existing.
(I realize those instructions say installed on fuerte, but I wanted to give it a try.)
To the point, I'm getting this error when rosinstall is called:
$ rosinstall . /opt/ros/groovy/ rosinstall.txt
ERROR in config: Yaml for each element must be in YAML dict form
Can I install it by hand? Cuz the content on the SVN link looks correct =/
Did anyone succeeded on installing the NAO simulator on Groovy? If so, what SVN link did you use?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80566/nao-simulator-installation-on-groovy/) by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please follow these instructions for installation:
http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/remote

The SVN locations are no longer valid (note that there is a "moved" readme in the directory).

Note that these instructions are for rosbuild, so you need to use the rosinstall file with a rosbuild workspace (not catkin).

You could also try the "devel" branch of the nao_robot GitHub repo for a catkin version, as currently discussed on the [Nao-ROS mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ros-sig-aldebaran).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1